# Exception in getting Facebook API User Access Token and C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am getting the following error:

> (OAuthException) client_secret should not be passed to
>   /oauth/access_token/

While I am calling the Facebook API to get me a "User Access Token" for further inquiries. My code is very simple:

```
string appId = "99999999"; // Long number  - Given by FB in my application page 
string appSecret = "98907kjlhkh908098"; // // Long string- Given by FB in my application page 
string code = "089789uokjj"; // Access Code in response to my first FB call - It is in query string of response
var fb = new FacebookClient ( appId , appSecret );

var parameters = new Dictionary<string , object>
{
    { "client_id", appId },
    {"redirect_uri" , "http://localhost:49773/Sample/Default.aspx"},
    { "client_secret", appSecret },
    { "code", code }
};

fb.Post( "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token/" , parameters );
```

How do I pass `Client_Secret`? Without that I cannot proceed and with that again I am getting exception!

Answer (score 0):

Little tutorial for ASP.NET for server-side flow (I am using ver. 6 of FB C# SDK):

1) create login button and bind onclick event on login page:

```
var loginWindowPopup = null;
var loginWindowTimer = null;

$(function ()
{
    $('#login_with_facebook').click(function ()
    {
        var popupWidth = 640;
        var popupHeight = 337;
        var xPosition = ($(window).width() - popupWidth) / 2;
        var yPosition = ($(window).height() - popupHeight) / 2;

        loginWindowPopup = window.open('/AuthSocialUser.aspx?facebookAuth=true', 
          'FacebookLoginWindow', 
          'location=1,scrollbars=1,menubar=0,status=0,toolbar=0' +
          ',width=' + popupWidth +
          ',height=' + popupHeight +
          ',left=' + xPosition +
          ',top=' + yPosition);

        if (loginWindowTimer == null)
        {
            loginWindowTimer = setInterval(CheckLogonWindowClose, 1000);
        }
    }
);

function CheckLogonWindowClose()
{
    if (loginWindowPopup.closed)
    {
        clearInterval(loginWindowTimer);
        location.reload();
    }
};
```

2) in AuthSocialUser.aspx popup window:

```
if (this.Request.QueryString["facebookAuth"] == "true")
{
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string,object>();
    parameters["client_id"] = "...";
    // parameters["scope"] = "email";

    string state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    parameters["state"] = state;
    this.Session.Add("state", state); //CSRF protection

    parameters["redirect_uri"] =    
      this.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("facebookAuth=true", "facebookAuth=false");

    parameters["response_type"] = "code"; // code can be exchanged for an access token

    parameters["display"] = "popup";

    this.Response.Redirect(new FacebookClient().GetLoginUrl(parameters).AbsoluteUri);
}
else
{
    string code = this.Request.QueryString["code"];
    string state = this.Request.QueryString["state"];
    string currentState = (this.Session["state"] != null ? 
        this.Session["state"].ToString() : null);

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(code) == true)
    {
        // set info in session: app not authorized & inject close window JS script
        return;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(state) == true || 
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentState) == true)
    {
        // session state expired & inject close window JS script
        return;
    }

    if (state != currentState)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("State does not match (CSRF?)");
    }

    //// get access token
    var fb = new FacebookClient();

    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("client_id", "...");
    parameters.Add("redirect_uri", "https://127.0.0.1
       /AuthSocialUser.aspx?facebookAuth=false");
    parameters.Add("client_secret", "...");
    parameters.Add("code", code);

    result = fb.Get("/oauth/access_token", parameters);

    string accessToken = result["access_token"];

    // use token in next requests, insert status to session state 
    // & inject close window JS script - simple: window.close();
}
```