# How to get an access token using C# SDK

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I updated the Facebook SDK to 6.0.10 and some code that used to work is not working anymore. I used to post on users' wall use the method below.

The class FacebookClient used to take the `AppId`, and `AppSecret` and I didn't gave it any access token for my application.

```
string uId = "SomeUid";
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(AppId,AppSecret );

string userFeedPath = String.Format("/{0}/feed", uId);

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
parameters.link = "Test@test";
parameters.message = "test";

try
{
    dynamic result = fb.Post(userFeedPath, parameters);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{

}
```

Now even if I try this,

```
FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();

fb.AppId = "1234...";
fb.AppSecret = "76e69e0c334995cecc8c....";
```

I'm getting this error:

> (OAuthException - #200) (#200) This API call requires a valid app_id.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you be sure that your credentials are still valid for the updated SDK? You may need to obtain new credentials (due, for example, to an upgrade in the type of OAuth being used).

Comment: for someone who faces problem in future, here's a complete tutorial: [Working with Facebook C# SDK](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/02/working-with-facebook-c--sharp-sdk.html)

Answer (score 32):

You will need to get the app access token by making the request.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new { 
    client_id     = "app_id", 
    client_secret = "app_secret", 
    grant_type    = "client_credentials" 
});
fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
```

Comment: Does this mean version 6.0 has breaking changes? I am just now starting to use V 6.0 but I was following a tutorial and I cant get it to work ... types are just not there that used to be there (looked at Codeplex and older version has the files). Frustrating needless to say ...

Comment: Hi Prabir. I tried this approach without any luck. First off, I think it should be result.access_token to get the value. But beyond that it seems like this will get the access token for the application, and not for a specific user of the application. It also sounds like the only way to get a user's access token is through the JavaScript SDK? Is that correct? Or does the C# SDK provide some other way that I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: thanks. i updated to result.access_token. it is for app access token. for user access token you need to use server side flow or use js sdk.

Comment: @prabir it would be awesome, if there was a concise documentation your this sdk. it s plain torture to use this sdk.

Comment: @DarthVader this has already been documented at http://csharpsdk.org/docs/faq.html What does not work? can you be more specific. if there is a bug you are supposed to be opening an issue in github. if you want to avoid breaking changes stick with v5.

Comment: I have searched for hours to find this information...thats all i need to find!! thanks alot prabir!

Comment: @prabir link is broken, please fix

Comment: It was showing URI Exception, then I added a code `dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
                {
                    client_id = "123......",
                    client_secret = "3be.....",
                    redirect_uri = "http://localhost:1234/"
                 });`

Answer (score 4):

For code -> user access token exchange in server-side flow - instead (ver. 5):

```
    FacebookOAuthClient oAuthClient = new FacebookOAuthClient();
    oAuthClient.AppId = "...";
    oAuthClient.AppSecret = "...";
    oAuthClient.RedirectUri = new Uri("https://.../....aspx");

    dynamic tokenResult = oAuthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(code);
    return tokenResult.access_token;
```

Now use (ver. 6):

```
    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    parameters.Add("client_id", "...");
    parameters.Add("redirect_uri", "https://.../....aspx");
    parameters.Add("client_secret", "...");
    parameters.Add("code", code);

    result = fb.Get("/oauth/access_token", parameters);

    string accessToken = result["access_token"];
```

(see: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/)

Comment: Full sample: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162613/exception-in-getting-facebook-api-user-access-token-and-c-sharp

Comment: Followed your code exactly, I get:
(OAuthException - #101) Error validating application. Cannot get application info due to a system error.

Comment: I think the gist is that a callback is required to happen. That means you have to provide a redirect url that will accept the "code" parameter and apply it to the user.

Comment: What is ***code*** variable? How I get code value ?

Comment: answer is not complete. I don'y know why this as a answer

Answer (score 4):

I have just started using this Facebook library yesterday and thought the lack of the ability to give me the access token without passing from JavaScript was a major shortcoming. Here is a helper that can get the access token. I hope this helps anyone who has had the same frustrations as myself. I think this should all work fine. I had something similar working on a website before I discovered the Facebook [NuGet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet) which has worked fine for approximately a year now.

If there's a better way please let me know.

```cs
public class FacebookHelper
{
    private string _appId;
    private string _appSecret;
    private string _accessToken;

    public string AccessToken
    {
        get
        {
            if (_accessToken == null)
                GetAccessToken();

            return _accessToken;
        }
        set { _accessToken = value; }
    }

    public FacebookHelper(string appId, string appSecret)
    {
        this._appId = appId;
        this._appSecret = appSecret;
    }

    public string GetAccessToken()
    {
        var facebookCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["fbsr_" + _appId];
        if (facebookCookie != null && facebookCookie.Value != null)
        {
            string jsoncode = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(FromBase64ForUrlString(facebookCookie.Value.Split(new char[] { '.' })[1]));
            var tokenParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(GetAccessToken((string)JObject.Parse(jsoncode)["code"]));
            _accessToken = tokenParams["access_token"];
            return _accessToken;
        }
        else
            return null;

       // return DBLoginCall(username, passwordHash, cookieToken, cookieTokenExpires, args.LoginType == LoginType.Logout, null);
    }

    private string GetAccessToken(string code)
    {
        //Notice the empty redirect_uri! And the replace on the code we get from the cookie.
        string url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri={1}&client_secret={2}&code={3}", _appId, "", _appSecret, code.Replace("\"", ""));

        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
        System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            using (response = request.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                string retVal = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return retVal;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private byte[] FromBase64ForUrlString(string base64ForUrlInput)
    {
        int padChars = (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4) == 0 ? 0 : (4 - (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(base64ForUrlInput, base64ForUrlInput.Length + padChars);
        result.Append(String.Empty.PadRight(padChars, '='));
        result.Replace('-', '+');
        result.Replace('_', '/');
        return Convert.FromBase64String(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, can you tell me a little more? I don't see a fbsr_[appId] cookie in my cookies list

Answer (score 2):

> There is another method to make calls to the Graph API that doesn't require using a generated app access token. You can just pass your app id and app secret as the access_token parameter when you make a call:

https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret

> The choice to use a generated access token vs. this method depends on
>   where you hide your app secret.

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

```
var client = new FacebookClient($"{appId}|{appSecret}");
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried some of the above samples only to find out that dynamic does not compile using xamarin studio. Here is what I did.

```
public class AccessTokenModel
{
    public string Access_Token { get; set;}
}

var fb = new FacebookClient();
var result = fb.Get ("oauth/access_token", new { 
    client_id     = App.FaceBookId, 
    client_secret = App.FacebookAppSecret, 
    grant_type    = "client_credentials" 
});
var accessToken = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenModel> (result.ToString ());
```

or

```
FBSession.ActiveSession.AccessTokenData.AccessToken;
```

Comment: I use WinForms and Unit Tests project. What is FBSession ?

Answer (score 0):

Hare is a real working Method:

```
protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
        {
            // Note: Facebook doesn't like us to url-encode the redirect_uri value
            var builder = new UriBuilder("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token");
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("client_id", this.appId);
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("redirect_uri", NormalizeHexEncoding(returnUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)));
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("client_secret", this.appSecret);
            builder.AppendQueryArgument("code", authorizationCode);

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                //Get Accsess  Token
                string data = client.DownloadString(builder.Uri);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                var parsedQueryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(data);
                return parsedQueryString["access_token"];
            }
        }
 private static string NormalizeHexEncoding(string url)
        {
            var chars = url.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length - 2; i++)
            {
                if (chars[i] == '%')
                {
                    chars[i + 1] = char.ToUpperInvariant(chars[i + 1]);
                    chars[i + 2] = char.ToUpperInvariant(chars[i + 2]);
                    i += 2;
                }
            }
            return new string(chars);
        }
```

Comment: How to get that `authorizationCode`