# How to get the Facebook access token using F#

Tags: facebook, f#, c#-to-f#

I am looking at the [Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.net/) for the first time and I want to implement it using F#.  I am trying to get the access token based on my application's appId, appSecret, and clientToken.  I am looking at the C# example on StackOverflow found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906486/how-to-get-an-access-token-using-c-sharp-sdk).

How do I translate this C# code?

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new { 
    client_id     = "app_id", 
    client_secret = "app_secret", 
    grant_type    = "client_credentials" 
});
fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
```

F# does not allow dynamic typing and I am not sure how to implement that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ImpromptuInterface.FSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImpromptuInterface.FSharp) NuGet package to enable dynamic lookup via the `?` operator. This would enable you to write `result?access_token`

The use of an anonymous type is actually more difficult to translate, because F# doesn't have those. The solution depends on how they're used, and while I don't know how the Facebook SDK consumes such values, I'm going to assume that it works the same way as ASP.NET Web API, which uses anonymous types as an alternative to a dictionary.

In that case, you'll need to first create a record with the appropriate properties:

```
type Credentials = { 
    client_id     : string
    client_secret : string
    grant_type    : string
}
```

this should enable you to create a new value of that type:

```
{ 
    client_id     = "app_id"
    client_secret = "app_secret"
    grant_type    = "client_credentials" 
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that C# `dynamic` does not exist in IL, and is compiled to just `object`. So in F#, you would have that value as `obj` and then use the `?` operator implementation from `ImpromptuInterface.FSharp` to pick its parts.