# Dynamically Generate Access Token of Graph API in c#

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I am creating Application for accessing facebook data in windows form c# . I want to get dynamically generated Access token for Graph Api. And also explain parameter of OAuth.

My code is....

var client = new FacebookClient();

client.AccessToken = ?????

Answer (score 1):

[How to get an access token using C# SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906486/how-to-get-an-access-token-using-c-sharp-sdk)

You will need to get the app access token by making the request.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new { 
    client_id     = "app_id", 
    client_secret = "app_secret", 
    grant_type    = "client_credentials" 
});
fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
```